# Gatling-tool Extracting cookie data

Tags: scala, cookies, gatling

I'm currently writing a test simulation with gatling and I've hit a brick wall. One of my post requests has an odd requirement. the request is:

```
.post("/checkout/cart/add/product/form_key/")
```

This post request wont complete with appending the form key on the end of the URL, the form key is stored in a cookie called: CACHED_FRONT_FORM_KEY

I need a way to grab the value in that cookie from the gatling cookiejar and to be used in the post request as follows:

```
.post("/checkout/cart/add/product/form_key/${FORM_KEY}")
```

I have done some googling and found a similar request:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/gXosGVnUuZA

But I'm unsure of how to implement this into a simulation file, I'm currently using gatling 1.4.3. Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [regexHeader check](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Checks#wiki-header-regex) on the Set-Cookie reponse header in order to capture the cookie value.

Comment: Getting the value of a cookie:

    .check(headerRegex("Set-Cookie","CACHED_FRONT_FORM_KEY=(.*)").saveAs("formkey"))

Comment: How do you access this formkey from another exec()?

Comment: @Mayumi Either with Gatling EL "${formkey}" or Session API.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Gatling 2 API, you can access cookies as follows:

```
.exec( session => {
  import io.gatling.http.cookie._
  import org.asynchttpclient.uri._
  import io.netty.handler.codec.http.cookie.ClientCookieDecoder.LAX.decode

  val cookies = session("gatling.http.cookies").as[CookieJar].get(Uri.create("https://www.someSite.com"))
  // for (ck <- cookies ) {
  //     val cc = decode(ck.toString()) 
  //     println(s"${cc.name} === ${cc.value}");
  // }

  val ck = cookies.filter( cookie => decode(cookie.toString()).name == "CookieName")
  println(decode(ck.toString()).value)

  session
})
```

Uncomment the iterator to view all the cookies in the current session

Comment: Looks like CookieJar is private in gatling-3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll add another answer.

For this Magento scenario I needed the form key, but using `headerRegex("Set-Cookie","CACHED_FRONT_FORM_KEY=(.*)").saveAs("formkey")` would return a value like

`1Nt86VNYoPP5WUtt; path=/; domain=example.com`

By using the following regex, I was able to extract just the `1Nt86VNYoPP5WUtt` value

`headerRegex("Set-Cookie","CACHED_FRONT_FORM_KEY=([^;]+)").saveAs("formkey")`

I then used it in my HTTP Post like

```
 http("add_to_cart")
 .post("/checkout/cart/add/product/12345")
 .formParam("form_key", "${formkey}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTTP Helper `getCookieValue` is another way to grab cookie data:

```
// add cookie to the session as CACHED_FRONT_FORM_KEY
.exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("CACHED_FRONT_FORM_KEY"))) 
.exec { session =>
  println(session("CACHED_FRONT_FORM_KEY").as[String]) // `.as[]` unwraps the value from the session object
  session
}
.post("/checkout/cart/add/product/form_key/${CACHED_FRONT_FORM_KEY}")
```

#### Sources

- [Gatling HTTP Helpers](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_helpers/#getting-a-cookie-value)
- [Gatling Debugging](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/debugging#print-session-values)